# about WPF GetResourceStream

Tags: c#, wpf

```
StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new uri("UIOnly;component/Images/my_work.png", UriKind.Relative));

if ((streamInfo != null) && (streamInfo.Stream != null))
{
      using (var stream = streamInfo.Stream)
      {

      }
}
```

when above code executed, the UIOnly.dll is locked until application exit, why??

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the DLL being "locked"?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the file handle is not released.

Have you tried explicit calling Close on the stream instead of just disposing it?